# Laravel 5.1 Create New User

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an existing application which has a table for users with passwords, I have updated the protected $table in the user model so the system knows which table to look at but for some reason when I try create a new user the system still tries to post the new user to the default Users table.

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'users'. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from [users] where [email] = test@test.com)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the only explanation is you're using hardcoded `users.` table somewhere. Check all your controllers (and other classes, `routes.php` and views if you have logic there) for `DB::` queries to the `users` table. You can easily do it with any text search tool, Sublime Text has one.

Comment: Searching 7041 files for "DB::table('users')"

0 matches :(

Comment: Search for `users` - because you may have raw queries. )

Comment: Look inside your `config/auth.php`. It happens you are using the database driver for users, which also requires the table to be set in the config...